# Could not get OpenVPN work in Linux Mint 18.3

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint, openvpn

When I import the .ovpn file in Network Connections > Import a saved VPN configuration I get this error:

[image]

> The file 'config.ovpn' could not be read or does not contain
>   recognized VPN connection information
>
> Error: the plugin does not support import capability.

**When I to start OpenVPN through the shell then it will startup and show this output:**

```
sudo openvpn --config aaa.ovpn 
Wed Apr  4 14:28:19 2018 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Wed Apr  4 14:28:19 2018 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Wed Apr  4 14:28:19 2018 WARNING: file 'aaa.p12' is group or others accessible
Wed Apr  4 14:28:19 2018 WARNING: file 'aaa-tls.key' is group or others accessible
Wed Apr  4 14:28:19 2018 Control Channel Authentication: using 'aaa-tls.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Wed Apr  4 14:28:19 2018 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194 [nonblock]
Wed Apr  4 14:28:20 2018 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194
Wed Apr  4 14:28:20 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
Wed Apr  4 14:28:20 2018 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194
Wed Apr  4 14:28:21 2018 [Server OpenVPN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194
Wed Apr  4 14:28:24 2018 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: block-outside-dns (2.3.10)
Wed Apr  4 14:28:24 2018 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:7: register-dns (2.3.10)
Wed Apr  4 14:28:24 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Wed Apr  4 14:28:24 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Apr  4 14:28:24 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Wed Apr  4 14:28:24 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.10.10.12/24 broadcast 10.10.10.255
Wed Apr  4 14:28:24 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

If I am correct the connection has been established under the tun0 interface. But It still does not work. My traffic is still going through my normal IP address and the resources behind this VPN are not accessible.

**My .ovpn file:**

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote xx.xx.xx.xx 1194 tcp-client
verify-x509-name "Server OpenVPN" name
pkcs12 aaa.p12
tls-auth aaa.key 1
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo adaptive
```

**Output of route**

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         RT-AC68U-55A0   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.10.10.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.10.99.0      10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
172.30.3.0      10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.7.0      10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.8.0      10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.12.0     10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.14.0     10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.19.0     10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.63.0     10.10.10.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

Comment: Dir you try to remove the `block-outside-dns` and `register-dns` config items before importing?

Comment: No I received this file as it is. I only changed the ip addresses before posting it. I searched for it and people say that this is some kind of Windows only thing.